# How can I convert all my Documents to Salesforce Files

Tags: lightning, appexchange

I am migrating to Lightning and would like to migrate my Documents to Files as suggested by [Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=docs_documents_to_files.htm).

Does anyone have any guides or tools that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably [this](https://altvia.com/migrating-documents-to-content-in-salesforce-com-2/) guide will help you - it is for converting all attachments AND documents to files.